# Assistance with python And Operator

Tags: python, operators

I'm trying to create a program similar to battleship in python (hobbyist)I've tried a few things and I can't seem to figure out why this program returns miss even when the conditions match. What am I missing here? thanks

````
import random
import os
import time


XAXIS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
YAXIS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


########Generate Test Enemy Position
enemyPosX = random.randrange(1,len(XAXIS))
enemyPosY = random.randrange(1,len(YAXIS))


print(enemyPosX)
print(enemyPosY)





looping = True
while looping:
    xAim = input("set X gun position (1-10):: ")
    yAim = input("set Y gun position (1-10):: ")

    xAim = int(xAim)  #thought maybe I was comparing string to int
    yaim = int(yAim)

    print("{} {} :: {} {} ".format(enemyPosX, xAim, enemyPosY, yAim)) # Check Values for problem

    if (xAim == enemyPosX) and (yAim == enemyPosY): #<---- Should both return true but nope
        print("HIT!!!")
        time.sleep(3)
        looping = False
    else:
        print("MISS!!") #<--Getttin Miss regardless of Input
        ```
````

Comment: Typo: `yaim = int(yAim)` should be `yAim = int(yAim)`

Answer (score 0):

This following line is your problem.

```
yaim = int(yAim)
```

Notice the difference in capitalisation. 
Therefore, in your if statement's condition, you are comparing yAim (which is still a string) and enemyPosY, which is an integer, which will lead to it being `False`.

```
if (xAim == enemyPosX) and (yAim == enemyPosY):
```